# C cross-platform sound input library

Tags: c, audio

What's the best free cross-platform c99 (or earlier) library for getting sound input (microphone, etc)?

Comment: You'd be better off asking for a library for the platforms you're interested it, rather than just "cross-platform". Finding one which works with Arduino and Altera isn't isn't going to help much if you want Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/).  It is an open source C-Library which supports many different audio driver back-ends on different platforms, including:

### Windows

- WDM
- DirectSound
- WASAPI (Vista and later only)
- ASIO
- MME

### Mac

- Core Audio (OS X)
- SoundManager (OS 7,8,9)

### Linux

- OSS
- ALSA
- Jack (still in development)

It also supports 32 and 64 bit versions of all the platforms.

The API is fairly clean and there are several good examples that are included in the source code.

Comment: You can also take a look to SDL, or RTAudio